# Can you use a fixed size type and pointers together in the same union?

Tags: c++, unions

I'm investigating the possibility of defining a structure for a packet. I would like to set header variables in the packet and then set a pointer to the data part of the packet. My end goal is to be able to send this packet to a low level library that takes only a uint8_t*. I created this quick program to test the feasibility and it does not seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t header;
        uint8_t* data;
    };
    uint8_t* packet;
} sometype;

int main() {
    sometype s;
    s.header = 3;
    s.data = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t) * 2);
    s.data[0] = 1;
    s.data[1] = 2;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << s.packet[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << s.header << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.data[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << s.data[1] << std::endl;
}
```

My output is

```
�
�
�
```

Which makes me realize I have some type of error in my code (I've never worked with union before). However, when I debug the program I can see the data in the union. Looking at the packet, I can see that this method does not appear to be working. The data in the packet is not 3, 1, 2. It is 300, 221, 020 instead.

```
(gdb) print s
$1 = {{header = 3 '\003', data = 0x613c20 "\001\002"}, packet = 0x400903 <main()+125> "\300\211ƿ`\020`"}
```

Is this method that I am attempting valid? From google searches I saw someone say you can use whatever datatypes you want. Do I have to pack the structure using a pragma to get this to work or is this method not feasible?

Comment: As the answer below states, you really can't do this since union members occupy the same space, that's the point of a union. I thought this might help you visualize how that works: http://ideone.com/tucKBP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unusual output is because you attempt to use `<<` to print a `uint8_t`.

Usually (although the C++ standard doesn't specify this), `uint8_t` triggers the character overload of `<<`, so you print out the glyph corresponding to that character code, instead of the integer.  To avoid this hiccup you could do `std::cout << static_cast<int>(s.header);` etc.

---

Note that in Standard C++ it is not permitted to write one member of a union and then read a different member, i.e. you may only read the same member that was last written.  The technique you are trying to use is called *union aliasing* and is not allowed in Standard C++, although compilers may seem to support it as an extension.

However, even if you're on a compiler that does offer union aliasing, you still won't be able to do `s.packet[i]` with your current struct definition. This is because `packet` overlaps with `header` and `data`. The byte value of `header` should not be a part of the address `packet` is pointing to, but your code treats it like it is.

I guess you mentally had a model of a single pointer and you can interpret the memory being pointed to by the pointer as either a char array,   or as a char followed by a char array. But your code doesn't reflect that (and in fact you can't do that at all, unless the lengths of the arrays are known at compile-time).

Since `header` and `data[0]` are not in contiguous memory, there's no way you are going to be able to have a single pointer that points to some fictitious memory block in which those two bytes are adjacent.  I would recommend giving up on this entire line of enquiry; just have a single memory block, and you can make functions that access particular parts of it.

Comment: This is the flaw that makes this method not feasible. I am unable to write to the header and data variables and then subsequently read the packet variable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use `#pragma pack(1)` to get the behavior most engineers expect.  And yes, this is how most communication low level software works.

Otherwise, compilers tend to align each element to its data size for performance and compatibility reasons.

There is enormous cross-compatibility with `#pragma pack()` across compilers.  See [this for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.4/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html).

Comment: I added the #pragma pack(1) and I get a segmentation fault when I try to access s.packet. Would this cause a segmentation fault if I tried passing s.packet to a function too?

Comment: Testing that out, it appears this method is not feasible. Are there suggestions to get the behavior that I want?

Comment: @rangeme:  What CPU are you executing this program on?

Comment: The [Atmega2560](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega2560) microprocessor.

Comment: I'm thinking I create a buffer and manually put my data in the correct spots, then pass that with the number of bytes to the low level library. Wanted a prettier way but it will do.